# ABI Compatibility between release and debug

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, shared-ptr, abi

When using GCC, given that I compile the same library sometimes in release and sometimes in debug, is the ABI guaranteed to be compatible?

(while using the same compiler)

I have an executable and some shared objects (some depend on others), I want to be able to swap out release/debug shared objects without recompiling everything but
only the shared objects in interest.

Is this possible, or is there some scenario where I might get some undefined behavior this way? (Assuming my code is strictly packed, and padded in both release and debug)

**EDIT:**

I'll elaborate on the problem we're seeing. We have a custom version of `intrusive_ptr`, in debug mode we have our own `intrusive_ptr` which has a **single** member that is a `boost::intrusive_ptr`, and in release we simply use `boost::intrusive_ptr`. The API of our `intrusive_ptr` is the same of `boost::intrusive_ptr`, and we don't have any virtual functions in the class.
What we are seeing is this: 
If we use all debug libs or all release libs all works well. If we mix debug executable with release libs, there is a memory leak from the `intrusive_ptr` and it does not release the object.

The sizeof our `intrusive_ptr` and `boost::intrusive_ptr` are identical, both in debug and release (our class does not add any size overhead on top).

So I am wondering what could be causing the leak, ABI difference are the only things that come to mind.

Ideas?

Comment: The terms "debug" and "release" are not well defined in gcc land, tends to be a feature of an IDE.  If your "debug" build uses libstdc++ in debug mode then no, the safe iterator feature changes the collection object layout.  Mixing causes random memory corruption.

Comment: Actually I've checked and the code does not compile with libstdc++

Comment: @MaxShifrin did you figured out the cause of your problem?

Comment: Yes, the ABI's are not guaranteed to be compatible, in our case this was some extra padding in the structure of the object as far as I recall. Hence we couldn't do pointer tricks this way and had to design around the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have known several compilers that generate incompatible code for release and debug (though these compilers are long since deprecated). In face I would not trust object modules to fully compatible unless they have been compiled with **Exactly** the same flags.

This is why makefiles (following GNU principles) and IDE like Eclipse build release/debug/profile objects into different directories. To make sure that they can never be mixed up.

Comment: We use generally the same flags between release/debug, we mostly change the optimization level and strip debug symbols from the release build. All other option as far as I can tell are the same. Obviously we build in general into 2 separate directories but there are certain scenarios where you would like to mix the objects of debug and release.

For example you deploy a system in release and than want to debug some specific feature in a given module, you should in theory be able to replace only that module with a debug version to be able to debug it. (during development time).

Comment: @MaxShifrin: There are very few compilers that give that guarantee that the object files are compatible.

Comment: why would there be few that do give this guarantee? I would expect that ALL compilers would ALWAYS give this guarantee unless you work hard on messing up the compilation somehow. After all what is exposed by the object file is addresses of functions/ classes - it's interface, it should not be different between release and debug no matter what optimization level I use. The internal implementation as far as I understand should be irrelevant, where am I wrong?

Comment: Turn on some optimizations will get rid of padding in objects (to save space), thus leaving with an ABI breakage that the linker will not spot. That's the first one I can think, does not take much to break an ABI.

Comment: This is also why you see companies will deliver two versions of a library when they ship libraries. A debug version and a release version (four if they also provide static and dynamic versions of the library).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html `Some GCC compilation options cause the compiler to generate code that does not conform to the platform's default ABI. Other options cause different program behavior for implementation-defined features that are not covered by an ABI.`

Answer (score 1):

Typically no, because the usual difference between a release and a debug build are just options to make debug stepping works better.  But unexpected behavior is still possible, if you define other options differently (such as integer size, target architecture, ??) between the release and debug builds, the caller parameters may not match the callee expectations.  There could also be issues with exception safety, and const-ness that the run time linker may not check.

Comment: We use obviously the same architecture of 64bits in both, integral variable sizes are the same in both compilations. (for the variables we use)